# PEAR Mail, SMTP Sessions for Newsletters?

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

when sending newsletters through a SMTP server using PEAR's Mail package, is there any way to specify some kind of "connection reuse" so that the PHP script won't have to create a new socket to the SMTP server for each individual mail?

That is of course without putting the adress of each recipient in only one e-mail, so that the indvidual recipient's won't see each others adresses.

Or doesn't SMTP allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the best solution is to put each destinee in black carbon. This guarantees that who receives the mail does not see other mail addresses and is a better solution than sending a mail for each destinee

This is feasible with php pear Mail package.

Comment: Actually to do what i suggested you need library phpmailer: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ as php pear mail seems to not support bcc and cc

Comment: Yes but that may look awkward to the recipient and some mail-providers, like gmail, seem to have a lower spam-threshold on not personally-addressed mails.

Comment: Well that's true. Personally i use this solution in my applications. Never had problem with spam and gmail. Actually many other e-commerce site and mailings list use this strategy

Answer (score 1):

PEAR Mail seems to be a hopeless case, but Zend's framework has addressed the issue and keeps the SMTP socket open for as long as the script runs (and the object exists): http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.multiple-emails.html

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is set the 'persist' param.  And then only use the factory method once - then you ensure that it is the same socket that is used.

something like this:

```
static $mail;
if (!is_object($mail)) {
    $mail = Mail::factory($options['mail_method'], $params);
}
$res = $mail->send($to, $mime_headers, $body);
```

If you call the mail::factory every time then a new socket will be created. In the above way you only create one socket.